# NSLayoutConstraints to UITextField - Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a simple setup with 3 views:

`view`, which has 1 subview `contentView`, which has 1 subview `emailField` (a `UITextField`).

`emailfField` is not aligning in centerY correctly. I got is this error:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e7d500 UIView:0x9e85c30.centerY == UITextField:0x9e4dbd0.centerY>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9e7cc00 UIView:0x9e85530.top == UIView:0x9e85c30.top>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x9e7f950 h=--& v=--& UITextField:0x9e4dbd0.midY == + 282.5>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x9e81e90 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x9e85c30.midY == + 240>")
```

My .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self initContentView];
[self initFirstView];
[self addConstraints];}

- (void)addConstraints {
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

//First View
//Email Field
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.emailField
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.contentView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];}

- (void)initContentView {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0f/255.0f green:239.0f/255.0f blue:239.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.contentView];

int frameHorizontalCenter = self.contentView.frame.size.width/2;
self.funView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frameHorizontalCenter-50, 100, 100, 100)];
self.funView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.funView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dog1"];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.funView];

self.descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frameHorizontalCenter - 140, self.funView.frame.origin.y + self.funView.frame.size.height, 280, 60)];
self.descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
self.descriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:63.0f/255.0f green:63.0f/255.0f blue:63.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
self.descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.descriptionLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
self.descriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.descriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.descriptionLabel];

self.emailField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frameHorizontalCenter -140, self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.height, 280, 45)];
self.emailField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
self.emailField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:63.0f/255.0f green:63.0f/255.0f blue:63.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
self.emailField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.emailField.placeholder = @"Epasts";
[self.contentView addSubview:self.emailField];}
```

I really don't understand what's wrong. Aren't constraints set correctly?

Comment: Could You simply provide all the code, where You set up Your views/subviews and all constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` to turn off conversion of autoresizing masks to constraints on `contentView` and `emailField`. Add additional constraints to `emailField` to specify the `x` position, `width` and `height` that it should use.

Comment: That did the trick. But I still got an error `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9c3eb90 H:[UITextField:0x9c36e60(280)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9c3ebf0 H:|-(20)-[UITextField:0x9c36e60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9c32b90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9c3ec20 UITextField:0x9c36e60.trailing == UIView:0x9c32b90.trailing + 20>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9c38f30 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x9c32b90]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9c366d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9c3eb00 UIView:0x9c32b90.trailing == UIView:0x9c366d0.trailing>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xb423670 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x9c366d0(320)]>"`

Comment: Looks like you're pinning width and pinning to superview leading and trailing? Hard to tell what's going on with just pointer values to views...

Comment: Removed the trailing constraint, leaving only leading and now it's working without errors. Thanks